# Placing restrictions on certificate extensions when proxying HTTPs with nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy to handle HTTPS for an application that talks HTTP. This is working great so far, but now I need to be able to restrict what kind of certificates I accept from the upstream server. In addition to the usual verification checks, I need to be able to also reject any certificate with name constraints or with policy mapping, as well as reject the certificate if certain extensions are marked as critical.

In openssl, I believe this could be achieved with the `verify_callback` of [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) by getting the x509 extensions and checking to see what's present/critical.

Is it possible to:

a) Set these kind of restrictions on certificate extensions in nginx configuration? It seems like the [ngx_http_ssl_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_conf_command) has a `ssl_conf_command` directive used to pass some configuration options to openssl but
I'm unsure of if this is relevant to reverse proxies or if it's capable of "custom" certificate validations.

or

b) Write a custom module that can perform additional verifications on the certificate received from upstream and break off the connection if they fail? I'm not so familiar will how modules work so any advice would be appreciated if this is a potential solution.

or

c) Modify openssl configuration files to achieve this? Perhaps it's possible to set these restrictions at the openssl level and not require any changes in nginx at all.

The relevant part of my config file looks like:

```
http {

  keepalive_timeout  65;
  access_log  nginx_access.log;

  server {

    listen 12312;

    location / {
      ...
      proxy_pass https://<ip_address_of_upstream_server>;
      proxy_redirect https://<<ip_address_of_upstream_server>> http://localhost:12312;
      proxy_ssl_certificate certs/client-cert.pem;
      proxy_ssl_certificate_key certs/client-key.pem;
      proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate  certs/root.pem;
      proxy_ssl_verify on;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!